# Not able to access AWS instance from AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have configured a load balancer in AWS with single instance. Attaching images about the configuration information below. I have one simple sprint boot application deployed into my instance (mentioned in image-2) which has simple rest API call.

[image]

[image]

When I try to access this load balancer URL using wget on putty, it returns below response. It shows connected in below output, but I am not sure why it is not connecting to my instance and returning the response of API that is deployed along with spring boot. Am I missing some configuration here?

wget http://internal-testelb-1533190738.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/

[image]

Comment: a) Does it work if you `wget` directly to the instance? b) What is the Security Group configuration on the instance?

Comment: What port is your application listening on and what protocol? What listeners have you configured in the load balancer?

Comment: Hi Narendra, did you able to solve it ?

Comment: Yes. this is solved. It was company network issue.